# How do I hide the index column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How am I supposed to remove the index column in the first row. I know it is not counted as a column but when I transpose the data frame, it does not allow me to use my headers anymore.

[image]

```
In[297] df = df.transpose()
        print(df)
        df = df.drop('RTM',1)
        df = df.drop('Requirements', 1)
        df = df.drop('Test Summary Report', 1)

        print(df)
```

This throws me an error **"labels ['RTM'] not contained in axis"**.

RTM is contained in an axis and this works if I do `index_col=0`

```
df = xl.parse(sheet_name,header=1, index_col=0, usecols="A:E", nrows=6, index_col=None)
```

but then I lose my (0,0) value "Artifact name" as a header. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the first column to become the column headers after transposing?

Comment: Yes sir! That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `.iloc`, to assign the column names to the first row after transposing. Then you can drop the first row, and clean up the name

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('ABCDE'),
                   'val1': np.arange(1,6,1),
                   'val2': np.arange(11,16,1)})
  id  val1  val2
0  A     1    11
1  B     2    12
2  C     3    13
3  D     4    14
4  E     5    15
```

Transpose and clean up the names

```
df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.iloc[0].index.name)
df.columns.name = None
```

`df` is now:

```
       A   B   C   D   E
val1   1   2   3   4   5
val2  11  12  13  14  15
```

---

Alternatively, just create a new DataFrame to begin with, specifying which column you want to be the header column.

```
header_col = 'id'
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != header_col]
pd.DataFrame(df[cols].values.T, columns=df[header_col], index=cols)
```

Output:

```
id     A   B   C   D   E
val1   1   2   3   4   5
val2  11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: df.iloc[0]! I almost searched how to address a cell in da ataframe but did not execute it. Thanks a lot. Do you know how can i not lose my header for column 0 which is 'Artifact Name'

Answer (score 2):

Using the setup from @ALollz:

```
df.set_index('id').rename_axis(None).T

       A   B   C   D   E
val1   1   2   3   4   5
val2  11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. Do you know how can I not lose my 'id' label?

Comment: If you want to keep `id`, just use `df.set_index('id').T`

Comment: Yes! I did that and it shows it in the console but when I write it to an excel file using xlsxwrite I lose the value of it.

Comment: I figured what i was doing wrong was df = df.T. :/ Sorry for the silly questions.